# getting started with scalafx: error in HelloScalaFX

Tags: scala, javafx

I've get scalafx sources from hg.

Than I successfully build it and make sbt publish-local.

Now I'm trying to make my own hello world.

I've put following dependencies in my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" % "scalafx" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

unmanagedJars in Compile += Attributed.blank(file(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") + "/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar"))
```

This lines I get from original scalafx library.

Than I copy lines from HelloScalaFX to my own copy and try to build it.

I've got strange error:

```
not enough arguments for constructor Stage: (d: javafx.stage.Stage)scalafx.stage.Stage
[error]   stage = new Stage {
[error]               ^
[error] one error found
```

IMHO it indicates some problems with stage wrapping.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: works for me.. https://github.com/OlegYch/scalafx-test (jdk7u7, windows, built from hg today)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite general for scala.

Version matters! If you build something for 2.9.2 scala and try to use this jar for 2.10.0 many conflicts may arise.

Comment: I've got the same problem, using the correct scalafx version doesn't seem to make anything better :(